# Dialogflow VoxImplant Outbound Call Issue

Tags: dialogflow-cx, voximplant

I recently started with Dialogflow and using VoxImplant for Phonegateway.
Reference: https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/integrations/dialogflow-cx#outbound-calling.

I am trying to make an outbound call to customer from call center with VoxImplant, but facing issue as below.

With syntax like -> const call = VoxEngine.callPSTN("customer-phone-num","call-center-num"),
I am able to call the customer number. But once after call is picked by the customer, there is no response and I am seeing error message as
2023-10-19 01:10:29.041 Executing JS command: CcaiParticipantAnalyzeContent with params [{conversationId = 8aGT2KX ; id = XTsD ; } ;  {eventInput = {languageCode = en ; name = WELCOME ; } ; } ;  ]
2023-10-19 01:10:29.041 JS error: The supplied object is not a media endpoint in /contactcenterai.js:183:13
CCAI.Participant/this.sendMediaTo@/contactcenterai.js:183:13

Any idea on this error please or any reference for outbound call scenario.